# Android Build job on Jenkins fails with Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: android, windows, git, jenkins

I'm setting up an Android Build job in Jenkins(1.589).
For the moment I have decided to use http authentication .
My code repo is on Git and I have successfully installed Git Plugin for Jenkins.

This seems a common error however in most instances ssh authentication is used and either an exception or an error code is available.

My Build job fails with following error.

```
>Started by user anonymous 
>Building in workspace C:\Users\hkarunasekara\.jenkins\jobs\Test_Android\workspace\androiddev 
> Wiping out workspace first. Cloning the remote Git repository 
> Cloning repository http://username:password@domain.com/scm/mob/androiddev.git
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\Users\hkarunasekara\.jenkins\jobs\Test_Android\workspace\androiddev # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://username@domain.com/scm/mob/androiddev.git
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://username@domain.com/scm/mob/androiddev.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Sending e-mails to: <email address>
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks for your input

### Addition

I tried executing the above 3 git commands as is via git bash

> git init C:\Users\hkarunasekara.jenkins\jobs\Test_Android\workspace\androiddev # timeout=10
>
> git --version # timeout=10
>
> git fetch --tags --progress http://username@domain.com/scm/mob/androiddev.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

At the 3rd command (fetch) i was prompted for the password.Wondering if the same happens when jenkins is trying to connect as I dont see a git command executing with the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a similar problem with a private repository on GitHub, building on a Windows slave.

My solution was to use the Credentials plugin to provide the username/password ([How to do that with GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth)), and then specify the credentials in the drop-down below the repository URL box.